# How should I store the keypressed and the title of the window ? Should I use separate lists or ....?

Tags: java

`JNI` `C` code sends a `java` method the *key pressed* and *the name/title of the window* where the key was pressed/typed.

I have to store both the name of window and the key typed for later purposes when I want to know which key was pressed at what time *(I also store the time)* and in which window. For example let the title of the window be `User grassPro - Stack Overflow` and I had typed something like `difference hashtable hashmap` in the search bar.

Later I want to retrieve these i.e the *keys typed* with the *window title*. I am able to get both these details,but I do not understand how do I store them . Should I store them in separate lists,use a tree or what ?

I think of storing each key typed with the name of the window. I do not like this approach but is there a better one ? If there is a thought the please share it.

*Note : Finally I have to write the data to a log file*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with JNI C, but it sounds like you should make a class with the 3 variables you want to save, and then make a list of this class.